# How to get $file with wp_generate_attachment_metadata?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert an image into a custom post type.  I've read to use `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` after using `media_handle_upload`.

```
   $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'art_upload[$i]', $pid );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $file);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id,  $attach_data );
```

How do i get the variable `$file`?

Answer (score 0):

i used this code to insert image in database

```
<?php
   $post = array(
      'post_content'   => $method, // The full text of the post.
      'post_name'      => $recipetitle, // The name (slug) for your post
      'post_title'     => $recipetitle, // The title of your post.
      'post_status'    => 'publish', // Default 'draft'.
      'post_type'      => 'recipespost', // Default 'post'.
      'post_author'    => 1, // The user ID number of the author. Default is the current user ID.
      'menu_order'     => '0', // If new post is a page, sets the order in which it should appear in supported menus. Default 0.
      'post_password'  => '', // Password for post, if any. Default empty string.
      'post_excerpt'   => '', // For all your post excerpt needs.
      'comment_status' => 'open' , // Default is the option 'default_comment_status', or 'closed'.
      'post_category'  => $recipetype, // Default empty.
    ); 
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post); 
    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'diet', $dyettype, true);

    $filename = $_FILES["recipeimage"]["name"];
    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();

    //file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
    $file_array = array(
            'name'          => $_FILES['recipeimage']['name'],
            'type'          => $_FILES['recipeimage']['type'],
            'tmp_name'      => $_FILES['recipeimage']['tmp_name'],
            'error'         => $_FILES['recipeimage']['error'],
            'size'          => $_FILES['recipeimage']['size'],
    );

    // required for wp_handle_upload() to upload the file
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => FALSE );

    if ( !empty( $file_array['name'] ) ) {
       // upload the file to the server
        $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload( $file_array, $upload_overrides );

            // checks the file type and stores in in a variable
        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $uploaded_file['recipeimage'] ), null );       
           // set up the array of arguments for "wp_insert_post();"
        $attachment = array(

            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $uploaded_file['recipeimage'] ) ),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_author' => $logged_in_user,
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'guid' => $uploads['url'] . '/' . $file_array['name']
        );

        // insert the attachment post type and get the ID
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $uploaded_file['recipeimage'] );
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        // update the attachment metadata
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id );
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, where would i put wp_insert_post()?